# How to render a "Fake" block, Forge 1.20.1

Tags: minecraft-forge

I want to render a fake block (a block that only has texture and can be skipped). I came to something like this, but I don't know what to give to the renderSingleBlock method

```
Minecraft.getInstance().getBlockRenderer().renderSingleBlock(blockstate, posStack, bufferSource, pakcedLight, packedOverlay, modelData, renderType);
```

I want to put the textures of the game blocks for the fake blocks, but if I can also put custom textures, that would be fine.